# Excluding matches on the beginning or end of a line on a Regex with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to define a regular expression in JavaScript that matches all ocurrences, excluding the ones on the beginning or on the end of a line.

I can exclude the ones on the beginning but not on the end.
For example:

```
const MULTILINE = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ANNA
ANNA lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor ANNA sit amet
`

MULTILINE.match(/ANNA\w+/gm)
// output: ["ANNA_END", "ANNA_BEGIN", "ANNA_MIDDLE"] ok

MULTILINE.match(/(?!^)ANNA\w+/gm))
// output: ["ANNA_END", "ANNA_MIDDLE"] ok

MULTILINE.match(/ANNA\w+(?!$)/gm))
// output: ["ANNA_EN", "ANNA_BEGIN", "ANNA_MIDDLE"] fail
// expected: ["ANNA_BEGIN", "ANNA_MIDDLE"]
```

As seen, it correctly identifies my last string, but extracts the last character (as if $ was being replaced by another \d expression).

I've read lots of documentation an tried several variations such as `MULTILINE.match(/ANNA\w+(?!ANNA\w+$)/gm))` but without success.

Any help here? :)

Comment: Match it as a whole word, `/ANNA\w+\b(?!$)/gm`, so `/(?!^)\bANNA\w+\b(?!$)/gm` might work in the end.

Comment: You may use: `/(?!^)\bANNA\w+\b(?=.)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ANN_END` returns `ANN_EN` match because `(?!$)` lookahead, when failing, makes the engine backtrack, and as the pattern right before `(?!$)` is `\w+`, a `+` quantified pattern, the backtracking enables a match to complete before the end of string. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9PRMZA/1) and pay attention at the red arrow that show backtracking at Step 9:

[image]

To disallow this partial word matching, you may add a word boundary, `\b`, or another lookahead, `(?!\w)`.

The complete solution to match `ANNA\w+` not at the start/end of the string will look like

```
/(?!^)\bANNA\w+\b(?!$)/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ajqGyT/1).

**Details**

- `(?!^)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the regex index is at the start of the string
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `ANNA` - a substring
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the regex index is at the end of the string.

JS demo:

```js
const MULTILINE = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ANNA_END
ANNA_BEGIN lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor ANNA_MIDDLE sit amet`;
console.log(MULTILINE.match(/(?!^)\bANNA\w+\b(?!$)/gm));
```

Comment: May i know what is the name of the tool ? which is showing step by step match ?

Comment: @Code That is one of the recent regex101 updates, the regex debugger.

Comment: @Wiktor Brilliant! I wasn't seeing that. Thank you for the answer and for presenting the **regex debugger**. It's a wonderful tool!